# OpenSSL on Heroku - Database connection lost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, openssl

Using Postgres on Heroku Cedar, when I try to verify a public key using OpenSSL the connection with the database is lost.

```
# Recreate the error using a Base64 encoded key (BASE64_KEY below) you can go into the console and do the following:

decoded_key = Base64.decode64(BASE64_KEY) 
public_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(decoded_key) 
public_key.verify(OpenSSL::Digest::SHA1.new, "", "")

# Database connection is lost when this fails.
```

When the verification passes everything is hunky dory. I can't seem to replicate this behaviour in development.

Any ideas as to why it happens? Even better, is there a work-around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone coming behind this, I ended up threading the verification process and reading out the result of the thread. This way the database connection of the main thread isn't lost.

Hardly ideal but it works!

Comment: We've stumbled into this exact same issue and has taken us a week to realise that it was this that is causing the loss of database connection. Did you ever get any further into the cause/resolution, or did you just leave your work around in?

Comment: Ended up leaving it in Fringley. Talked extensively with support about it and in the end their conclusion was "yup, OpenSSL's a bitch!".

In saying that, I never had any trouble with the workaround. You need to watch out for memory leaks but it was never a problem for us and we maintained several hundred thousand authentications this way.

Comment: Yeah, we've had the same lack of resolution.  I have just managed to fix it though!  We are running unicorn and using the Heroku recommended unicorn file which at the bottom of the file has some code to deal with reconnecting the database on threaded servers.  I copied this code into our method after the SSL code and hey presto - it works!  Here's the article: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/concurrency-and-database-connections

Answer (score 0):

Reconnect your Heroku database after performing the SSL code using: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/concurrency-and-database-connections